# EF Core migration for DateTime to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am looking to create a migration for a series of objects which currently use `DateTime` properties and translate them into `DateTimeOffset` properties instead. I've stripped most of them out of this example but they were similar:

```
public partial class DatetimeOffset : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Message>(nameof(Message.SendingDate), nameof(Message), nameof(DateTimeOffset));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Message>(nameof(Message.SendingDate), nameof(Message), "datetime");
    }
}
```

For these purposes just assume that `Message` looks like this:

```
public class Message {
    public DateTime SendingDate { get; set; }
}
```

My upgrade works just fine, however, the downgrade doesn't since it's a lossy conversion between DateTimeOffset and DateTime. What is a way to cast this? I don't care about precision loss.

I am using .NET Core 2.2 and EF Core 2.2.

Comment: do you have any error message ?

Comment: ```The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.```

Comment: I ended up solving it using a 7-digit precision ```datetime2``` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a `datetime2` column with 7 digits of precision, which will convert just fine:

```
public partial class DatetimeOffset : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Message>(nameof(Message.SendingDate), nameof(Message), nameof(DateTimeOffset));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Message>(nameof(Message.SendingDate), nameof(Message), "datetime2(7)");
    }
}
```